# Power BI - Counting rows based on time between timestamps

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table of actions that include timestamps - I'd like to be able to do a count of actions by type, excluding actions of the same type that are within 10 seconds of a previously counted action.

For example:
DATA

```
Row Action  DateTime  
1   A       11/14/2019  11:00:05 PM  
2   A       11/14/2019  11:00:11 PM  
3   A       11/16/2019  11:00:46 PM  
4   B       11/16/2019  11:06:46 AM  
5   C       11/22/2019  11:09:26 PM  
6   C       11/22/2019  11:09:30 PM  
7   B       11/22/2019  11:09:31 PM  
8   C       11/22/2019  11:09:37 PM   
9   A       11/22/2019  11:50:02 AM
```

RESULTS

```
Action  Count
A       3
B       2
C       2
```

Action A occurs 4 times - however, row 2 is within 10 seconds of row 1, so it is skipped. 
Action B occurs 2 times and they both count. 
Action C occurs 3 times - row 6 is within 10 seconds of row 5 and is skipped. Row 8 is within 10 seconds of row 6, but it gets counted because 6 was skipped (the comparison should be against row 5).

Comment: Honestly? I can't even figure out where to start. In Excel I would break this up into an IF(AND) and a COUNTIFS - something like:  
=IF(AND(B2=B1,C2<=(C1+".00012")),0,1)  
=COUNTIFS(B2:B10,J2,F2:F10,1)  
  
I'm relatively new to PowerBI and have been struggling with chaining things together.

Comment: I created a measure based on activity ID, but it doesn't take the timestamps into account -- Call = COUNTAX(Filter('Activity',[ActivityID]=1,[ID])